# Errors in imported library of image

Tags: flutter, dart

When I am importing image library

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:image/image.dart';
```

I am getting the error that this import

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when same keyword is used by different package at that situation the IDE gets confused and throws this error .

This is how you solve it:
use `**img.Image**` instead of **Image**  this way you tell the ide which package to import it from. This will generally
solve the issue.